# Initialize an RDD to empty

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD called

```
JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> existingRDD;
```

Now I need to initialize this  `existingRDD` to empty so that when I get the actual rdd's I can do a union with this `existingRDD`.
How do I initialize `existingRDD` to an empty RDD except initializing it to null?
Here is my code:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> existingRDD;
if(ai.get()%10==0)
{
    existingRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("s3://manthan-impala-test/kinesis-dump/" + startTime + "/" + k + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "/",
    NullWritable.class, Text.class, TextOutputFormat.class); //on worker failure this will get overwritten                                  
}
else
{
    existingRDD.union(rdd);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do. You want to create a union on a empty RDD? What for?

Comment: Yes. When i loop through eachRDD i mean foreachRDD in my code i need to do union of rdd's to this existingRDD so that final i can save this existingRDD to my s3

Comment: Why can't you simply set the `existingRDD` to `rdd` in the first iteration after writing it to s3?

Answer (score 30):

To create an empty RDD in **Java**, you'll just to do the following:

```java
// Get an RDD that has no partitions or elements.
JavaSparkContext jsc;
...
JavaRDD<T> emptyRDD = jsc.emptyRDD();
```

I trust you know how to use generics, otherwise, for your case, you'll need:

```java
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,List<String>>> emptyRDD = jsc.emptyRDD();
JavaPairRDD<String,List<String>> emptyPairRDD = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(
  existingRDD
);
```

You can also use the `mapToPair` method to convert your `JavaRDD` to a `JavaPairRDD`.

In **Scala** :

```scala
val sc: SparkContext = ???
... 
val emptyRDD = sc.emptyRDD
// emptyRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.EmptyRDD[Nothing] = EmptyRDD[1] at ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val emptyRdd=sc.emptyRDD[String]
```

Above statement will create empty RDD with `String` Type

From SparkContext class:

> Get an RDD that has no partitions or elements

```
def emptyRDD[T: ClassTag]: EmptyRDD[T] = new EmptyRDD[T] (this)
```

Comment: I like this way. I was doing `val emptyRdd:RDD[String]=null`.

Answer (score 0):

In scala, I used "parallelize" command.

```
val emptyRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(""))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that creates an `RDD[String]` with one entry, the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

@eliasah answer is very useful, I am providing code to create empty pair RDD. Consider a scenario in which it is required to create empty pair RDD (key,value). Following scala code illustrates how to create empty pair RDD with key as String and value as Int.

```
type pairRDD = (String,Int)
var resultRDD = sparkContext.emptyRDD[pairRDD]
```

RDD would be created as follows :

```
resultRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.EmptyRDD[(String, Int)] = EmptyRDD[0] at emptyRDD at <console>:29
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, create the empty RDD was a little complex. I tried using the scala.reflect.classTag but it not work either. After many tests, the code that worked was even more simple.

```
private JavaRDD<Foo> getEmptyJavaRdd() {

/* this code does not compile because require <T> as parameter into emptyRDD */
//        JavaRDD<Foo> emptyRDD = sparkContext.emptyRDD();
//        return emptyRDD;

/* this should be the solution that try to emulate the scala <T> */
/* but i could not make it work too */
//        ClassTag<Foo> tag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Foo.class);
//        return sparkContext.emptyRDD(tag);

/* this alternative worked into java 8 */
    return SparkContext.parallelize(
            java.util.Arrays.asList()
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, create empty pair RDD as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<T, T> emptyPairRDD = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(SparkContext.emptyRDD());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below snippet:

```
val emptyRDD = spark.emptyDataset[T].rdd
```